# File replication

Tags: azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-actor

I have a Web API stateless-service that bring a file from a client and transfers it to an actor-service (for deferred ETL operations). File size limited up to 20MB.

Is it good idea to tranfer file directly (in-memory as a byte array) from one service to another? Or there any feature like a file-based state to replicate file within the cluster and further processing?

P.S. It is impossible (due to legal reasons) to upload it anywhere before processing.

P.P.S. SF cluster is on-premises installation.

Comment: What about Azure Blob storage?  Could you store the object there and then drop a message in a queue letting the other services know a file is ready for processing?

Comment: It the last case to upload file anywhere, as I wrote due to legal reason. I'd prefer working with the file within the cluster only.

Comment: I'm not sure I see a way to do this (still new to Service Fabric myself).  You have a stateless service, meaning you need to store the file somewhere in case the service goes down while processing the file.  But you can't store the file anywhere outside the cluster.  Since this cluster is on-prem, does that alleviate any of the legal issues?  Probably not since you pointed that out originally -- but I thought I'd ask...  :)

Answer (score 0):

It is not a good idea to do that for a few reasons:

1 - If you store your files in Reliable Collections, it would make your collections too big and slow down the replication, as every update to your collections would be replicated to other nodes, it would be also expensive(time) to move services around the cluster.

2 - if you don't store it on any collection and leave it in memory, Service Fabric could try to move your service around the cluster and you risk to loose the data.

3 - When you upload the file, you must return a confirmation to the user, to avoid let them waiting until the processing is complete, locking server resources is a bad idea.

4 - Saving it to the disk won't replicate the file, and if your service move to other nodes, you loose access to the file.

There are many reasons, if can't save it somewhere (like a file share), you can take these risks.

If you still prefer to go this route, I would suggest:

- Send the content to the actor that will process it, the actor will save it to the actor state.
- Register a timer (or reminder, dependning on your requirementts) in the actor for triggering the processing of this file.
- Create the logic after the processing to deactivate the timer and them save the output to somewhere after processed.
- Deactivate the actor and delete the state.

Using the actor state to store each file will make it more flexible, you might register the file in your actor at one node, and if the actor is moved, the actor state will be still available when it get activated on other node.

> Keep in mind that your cluster has nodes and they may fail, so you
>   should not rely on their memory or disks to save state, unless
>   replicated to others with different reliability guarantees, like azure
>   storage.

Comment: You are right, I need to save it only before ETL-actor takes it and processed. After that file (or item in reliable collection) shall be removed. Approximate nominal time to process a single file - less than 500 ms.
What kind of reliable collection is the best choise in my case (to keep a large object for a short time)?

Comment: I've updated my answer to add extra info. I honestly never stored large files in the collection, generally I store the file metadata and load it on demand. You must do some testing to check if the size would affect the performance of your system, and if the runtime won't complain, today is 20Mb, it might increase, you should take this into account as well. So the best answer is do a proof of concept and test if it is acceptable with 20Mb, 50Mb, and maybe plan to store it in another shared storage available to all nodes and the actor store just the file information for processing.